# How to declare Time in Go?

Tags: go

I have been walking through the tutorials and know how to declare variables but can not find how to declare of variable as type Time.

How Time is declared in Go?

Comment: http://tour.golang.org/#1 and http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html.

Comment: I had this same question trying to declare `var start Time` but what I was looking for was `var start time.Time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find plenty of example of [`Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) variable declaration in the [package `time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time) itself, as in the [Duration example](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Duration)

```
 t0 := time.Now()
```

This is using the "[short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)", which is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types.